# In Cohen's Independence of Continuum Hypothesis, can someone explain to me his definition of the $a_\delta$'s at the beginning of the paper?

Tags: set-theory, continuum-hypothesis

Cohen's paper

> *The independence of the Continuum Hypothesis*, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA. 1963 Dec; 50(6): 1143–1148 ([PMC221287](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC221287/))

begins by invoking the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem to assert the existence of $M$ which is countable and then asserts therefore there exist distinct sets $a_\delta$, which each a subset of $\omega$ (set of integers), with $\delta$ running from 0 to $\aleph_2$. Can someone explain to me how can he make this claim without knowing a priori that CH is false?

I ask this because:

1. $\omega$ is countable and therefore there exists a bijection  to the natural numbers.
2. $a_\delta$ is a subset of a countable set $\omega$, which makes it an element of the power set of $\omega$,  $P(\omega)$, the continuum or real numbers
3. Since he specifically states distinct sets and they are enumerated by $\delta$ taking on values between 0 and $\aleph_2$, the set which is the union of all the $a_\delta$s would be size $\aleph_2$ with a bijection existing between it and a subset of the real numbers since the $a_\delta$s are all elements of the reals.
4. By the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem, the real numbers are at minimum size $\aleph_2$, i.e. CH fails.

This seems to imply that Lowenheim-Skolem theorem alone can imply CH fails.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Edit: Thank you for your responses. I added link to paper per your suggestion. I am new to forcing and have heard that Cohen used an early form of it. This statement occurs in paper however before forcing is defined. I think I understand the concept that you start with what is a true statement, and "force" it to remain true. Is he assuming CH fails (since the definition of $a_\delta$'s are equivalent to the statement CH fails) at the beginning then and looking for a contradiction/inconsistency with each of the ZFC axioms to show unprovability of CH within ZFC axiomatic system? Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: This question would be improved by a link to the paper you're asking about.

Comment: I presume you are referring to http://www.pnas.org/content/50/6/1143.citation.  Note that $\aleph_2$ isn't the "real" $\aleph_2$, it's the set in $\mathfrak{M}$ which the model "thinks" is $\aleph_2$, but since $\mathfrak{M}$ is countable it is really a countable set, so there is no problem finding an injection from it to subsets of $\omega$.  This injection won't necessarily be in $\mathfrak{M}$ so it won't affect what $\mathfrak{M}$ thinks about CH.  At least, that's my (non-expert) reading...

Comment: Although this comment has nothing to do with what you specifically asked, I can't help but suggest that, if you are learning forcing for the first time, you should first follow modern texts and then take a look at the original papers.

Comment: I agree with @Burak completely. Reading Cohen's paper is only useful if you are looking for historical account or some specific reference for the earliest proof of one thing or another. Forcing had changed its face several times since Cohen. And usually for the better.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I remember trying to read his book Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis *before* I was exposed to forcing via modern texts. After taking a course on the topic, I reread some parts of the book, everything in the book made much more sense than it had before. One of the upsides of reading his book is that Cohen tries to intuitively motivate what he is doing more than textbooks.

Comment: Please see edit. Thank you for responses!

Comment: Re your update: If he assumed CH failed and found a contradiction with ZFC, that would be a proof that CH is *implied* by ZFC, not merely *consistent*.  Obviously he can't do that.  He wants to construct a *model* of ZFC in which CH is false.  This will prove consistency of $\lnot$CH, since you can't construct a model in which contradictory statements are true (unless your underlying set theory, here ZF, is itself inconsistent).  $\mathfrak{M}$ is not that model, but it's used to construct a second model $\mathfrak{N}$ which is.

Comment: The first comment from @NateEldredge essentially answers the question.  The index $\delta$ (of $a_\delta$) does not range over the genuine $\aleph_2$ (which would mean that that CH already failed in the real world) but rather over the set ${\aleph_2}^M$ that $M$ thinks is $\aleph_2$, i.e., the set that satisfies in $M$ the formula "$x$ is the second uncountable cardinal." This ${\aleph_2}^M$ is, like everything else in $M$, a countable set in the real world.

Comment: Thanks again. The comments help. I also found a topic here called uncountable sets in countable models that seemed to ask a similar question last June and had good feedback regarding Skolem's paradox and that a function which is a bijection to omega isn't allowed within the model, which can make a countable set "uncountable"